# jQueryReplacing images at time intervals

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

I'm trying to add christmas lights to my logo. I was going to do this in flash but I'm trying to move away from flash so I decided to try it with jQuery.

A quick google search returned [this tutorial](http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2009/05/replacing-images-at-time-intervals.html). Which did a pretty good job getting me on the right track. The problem is that I don't want the images to fade in and out so I replaced

```
$active.fadeOut(function() $next.fadeIn().addClass('active');
```

with 
    $active.show(function() $next.show().addClass('active');

The problem with this is that it only rotates though the images once then stops. I tried using `hide` instead but it does a weird zoom-out effect.

In short,  I have 4 images and i'm trying to cycle though them using this code:

```
    function swapImages(){
  var $active = $('#myGallery .active');
  var $next = ($('#myGallery .active').next().length > 0) ? $('#myGallery .active').next() : $('#myGallery img:first');
  $active.show(function(){
  $active.removeClass('active');
  $next.show().addClass('active');
  });
}
  $(document).ready(function(){
      setInterval('swapImages()', 1000);
})
```

Html:

```
  <div id="myGallery">
      <img src="br_xmas_1.png" class="active" />
      <img src="br_xmas_2.png" />
      <img src="br_xmas_3.png" />
     <img src="br_xmas_4.png" />
</div>
```

[See partly working full code here](http://files.bandonrandon.com/xmas.html) or not working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BandonRandon/CSaRM/)

Comment: Have you tried with show() / hide() instead of fadeIn() / fadeOut() ?

Comment: yeah that was the first thing i tried. show was fine, but hide made the image zoom out. It actually looks like the class is being applied right it's just not hiding the image correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this;

```
function swapImages() {
    var $current = $('#myGallery img:visible');
    var $next = $current.next();
    if($next.length === 0) {
        $next = $('#myGallery img:first');
    }
    $current.hide();
    $next.show();
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    // Run our swapImages() function every 0.5 secs
    setInterval(swapImages, 500);
});
```

[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/karalamalar/CSaRM/1/)

**Bonus** ([Random change](http://jsfiddle.net/karalamalar/CSaRM/2/))

```
function swapImages() {
    var random = Math.floor(Math.random()*3),
        $current = $('#myGallery img:visible');
    $current.hide();
    if($current.index() == random) {
        random = ++random % 4;
    }
    $('#myGallery img').eq(random).show();
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    // Run our swapImages() function every 0.5 secs
    setInterval(swapImages, 500);
});
```

Comment: Cool, I got it working by changing       `$active.removeClass('active');` to `      $active.hide().removeClass('active');` But I think your code is much cleaner. Only one question. Can anything be done about the jumpyness?

Comment: What do you mean by **jumpyness**?

Comment: What i mean is apparently FF was being a jerk. Chrome is happy. disregard and thanks for the help!

Comment: I added a bonus, did you see it? :)

Comment: @enre, yeah thanks that's pretty cool. Javascript is an amazing language which i'm still getting a grasp on.

Comment: Okay, So it seems like Jquery no conflicts is causing a 'function undefined error' do you know how I'd go about fixing this? http://files.bandonrandon.com/xmas2.html

Comment: @BandonRandon you can update your custom.js with [this](http://pastebin.com/mjqGXX2F) script.

Comment: Looks like the real problem was just the quotes around `setinterval` oops!

Answer (score 1):

Ah, already answered.

Try this [one](http://jsfiddle.net/SuEgt/)

You've used show() function which adds display:block style to the element. So, after one run all of the images were displaying at once and the last one was on top of the others so that one was displayed.