# global jQuery variable with no conflict

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I know this is going to be super simple for someone but i've just spent 2 hours trying to figure it out.

How do I use a function inside of jquery no conflict. I keep getting `Uncaught ReferenceError: swapImages is not defined (anonymous function)` if I don't use jquery no conflict the code works fine. (I have to use no conflict as it's built into WordPress)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    function swapImages() {
        var $active = $('#myGallery .active');
        var $next = ($('#myGallery .active').next().length > 0) ? $('#myGallery .active').next() : $('#myGallery img:first');
        $active.show(function () {
            $active.show().removeClass('active');
            $next.show().addClass('active');
        });
    }
    // Run our swapImages() function every 5secs
    setInterval('swapImages()', 500);
})
```

[See the original question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8366684/jqueryreplacing-images-at-time-intervals)

Comment: Why dont you get your function in the global scope?

Comment: Then `$ === jQuery` would not be available unless she used `window.swapImages = function() { ... }`. But using globals is bad anyway...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you use setInterval improperly. **Never** pass a string but always pass a function - passing a string is just as bad as using `eval`:

```
setInterval(swapImages, 500);
```

Then you do not need any global variables/functions.

In case you need to pass any arguments to the function, you'd wrap it in an anonymous function:

```
setInterval(function() { /* your code/function call */ }, 500);
```

Comment: Well there went an evening, should have asked earlier!

Answer (score 0):

```
setInterval(function(){swapImages()}, 500);
```

Comment: You don't need the anonymous function.  `setInterval(swapImages, 500)` works just fine.