# How to set an interval and increment a value at the same time?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im trying to solve a problem using a different approach other than the method discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8366684/jqueryreplacing-images-at-time-intervals)

**So I have the relevant html like so:**

```
<div id="main-container"></div>
<div id="list-container">
    <ul id="list">
        <li class="thumb"><img src="img/thumb-image1.jpg"></li>
        <li class="thumb"><img src="img/thumb-image2.jpg"></li>
        <li class="thumb"><img src="img/thumb-image3.jpg"></li>
        <li class="thumb"><img src="img/thumb-image4.jpg"></li>
        <li class="thumb"><img src="img/thumb-image5.jpg"></li>
        <li class="thumb"><img src="img/thumb-image6.jpg"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

then somewhere theres an img folder containing 6 images named:

> image1.jpg image2.jpg image3.jpg image4.jpg image5.jpg image6.jpg

And using jquery, I'm trying to basically swap the images inside its container div by manipulating the css and the list index at a time interval of say 3secs. so my first guess was this:

```
$('#list li').each(function(index){

$('#main-container').css({
    'background':'url("img/image'+(index+1)+'.jpg")'
    });
```

Unfortunately, its not working as I want it to. it just spits the last index which is 5 so the image shown ended up as image6 instead of the first image1 then 3secs later, image2 and 2secs again, image3 will show up and so on.

So how can I incorporate the `setInterval()` so the index changes creating the effect of an image rotation.

**Note:**

`<div id="main-container"></div>` is just an empty container that will serve as a placeholder for the images stored in the img folder when called dynamically.

actually, in the js file, the code below works when the thumbnail is clicked.

```
$('#list li').each(function(index){

    $(this).on('click', function(){
        $('#main-container').css({
        'background':'url("img/image'+(index+1)+'.jpg")'
        });
    });
});
```

My objective was that, even if the thumbnails are not clicked, the equivalent large images should rotate inside the `#main-container` creating a continuous slideshow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
var count = 0;
var imgCOUNT = $('#list li').length;
$('#main-container').css({'background-image' : 'url(img/image1.jpg)','transition' : 'background-image 1s','-webkit-transition' : 'background-image 1s','-moz-transition' : 'background-image 1s'});
var interval = setInterval(function() {
    count++;
    var index = count%imgCOUNT+1;
    $('#main-container').css("background-image", "url(img/image" + index + ".jpg)");
}, 3000);
```

**Alternate solution for transitions in Firefox**

```
var count = 0;
var imgCOUNT = $('#list li').length;
$('#main-container').css({'background-image':'url(img/image1.jpg)'});
var interval = setInterval(function() {
    count++;
    var index = count%imgCOUNT+1;
    $('#main-container').fadeTo(350,.1,function() {
        $(this).css("background-image", "url(img/image" + index + ".jpg)");
    }).delay(350).fadeTo(350,1);
}, 3000);
```

Comment: yeah it works! any idea how we can apply a fade in or fade out at each iteration? thanks a lot

Comment: This doesn't use the image count or paths from the `<li>` tags which I thought the OP asked for.

Comment: @shaun5 opps! type error. pause in debugger. what could be the prob?

Comment: @shaun5 its ok now but the image is still not fading.

Comment: shaun5 its all working now. but honestly, @jfriend00 jsfiddle example has a much smoother transition and also the first image is visible before it starts to animate. unfortunately, i cant get his code to work on my script lol

Comment: @shaun5 thank you very much! its all working smooth in chrome now though in firefox, the fade is not working. but anyway, i think its a css issue and the main problem is now solve.

Comment: @jfriend00 thank you very much for your help. although im still having problem as to why the code is not working in my script, the fact that the working example in jsfiddle is working fine, you already solved the question. so thank you too.

Comment: @anagnam I've added a second solution.  You can play around with the three timings and opacity to get a transition you like.

Answer (score 5):

OK, now that it is clearer what you're trying to actually do, here's how I would suggest doing it.  This will run indefinitely, assigning successive images from the `li` tags to `#main-container`.

```
(function() {
    // create local scope to isolate common variables
    // get image count and paths from the actual HTML so nothing is hard-coded
    var images = $('#list li img');
    var index = 0;
    var target = $("#main-container");

    function next() {
        var src = images.eq(index).attr("src");
        target.css("background-image", 'url(' + src + ')');
        index++;
        // if we've run out of images, start over
        if (index >= images.length) {
            index = 0;
        }
    }
    // execute the first one immediately, then subsequent ones with setInterval()
    next();
    setInterval(next, 3000);
})();
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/RuFBS/

---

Earlier answers before the HTML was provided:

It is unclear exactly what your trying to set the image on, but here's a way to iterate through the various images on an interval timer and apply one to each `<li>`.  If you want to apply the image to something different, then please disclose the relevant HTML so we can see what you're trying to target.  Here's a way to cycle through all the images with an interval timer:

```
(function() {
    // create local scope to isolate common variables
    var targets = $('#list li');
    var index = 0;
    var interval = setInterval(function() {
        targets.eq(index).css("background-image", "url(img/image" + index + ".jpg)");
        index++;
        if (index >= targets.length) {
            clearInterval(interval);
        }
    }, 3000);
})();
```

Personally, if the interval has a specific number of iterations, I tend to use `setTimeout()` instead like this:

```
(function() {
    // create local scope to isolate common variables
    var targets = $('#list li');
    var index = 0;
    function next() {
        targets.eq(index).css("background-image", "url(img/image" + index + ".jpg)");
        index++;
        if (index < targets.length) {
            setTimeout(next, 3000);
        }
    }
    next();
})();
```

If you're really just trying to rotate the images on `#main-container` (which has nothing to do with `#list li`), then you can do that like this:

```
(function() {
    // create local scope to isolate common variables
    var index = 0;
    var numImages = 6;
    var target = $("#main-container");
    function next() {
        target.css("background-image",  "url(img/image" + index + ".jpg)");
        ++index;
        if (index < numImages) {
            setTimeout(next, 3000);
        }
    }
    next();
})();
```

Comment: Added several options based on what the OP is actually trying to do (which is not clear).

Comment: thanks for the help but when trying out your code, it throws a syntax error. the `index++` is said to be unexpected identifier.

Comment: I needed the `list li` so i can keep track of the no. of images in the list instead of hardcoding the number of images.

Comment: I put a note below my question for further clarification. thank you

Comment: I have updated my question by showing relevant html code. hope this gives a more clearer view of what I'm trying to achieve. thanks

Comment: @anagnam - OK, I've added a new option at the start that cycles `#main-container` indefinitely through the images in your `<li>` tags using `setInterval()` as requested.  You would need to have the appropriate CSS on `#main-container` to establish its size so the background image has room to display.

Comment: I tried your revised code but it doesnt seem to work. however, theres no console error. btw, I already have a document ready function soewhere in my script so I suspect its conflicting with your code when directly copied. Im still new to the language so pardon me if i dont quite get it. So shall i put it immediately after my document ready function? just to test if it works?

Comment: @anagnam - it works when installed properly.  Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/RuFBS/

Comment: i can see in the jsfiddle that its working. however, when pasted inside my js file, its not working.

Comment: @anagnam - you'd have to show us your actual web page so we could see why it isn't working.  It could be your HTML, your CSS or your JS.  Not sure.  My suggested JS works as you can see it in the jsFiddle.

Answer (score 0):

```
var count = 0;

$('#list li').each(function(index) {
    count += 1;

    $('#main-container').css({
        'background':'url("img/image' + count + '.jpg")';
    });
});
```

Comment: @anagnam: not that i want to promote posting buggy code, but you should be able to fix the syntax error. Hes just missing a `'`...

Comment: @prodigitalson I actually corrected it and tested it before commenting. and its not actually the syntax error but the code itself is not working.

Comment: Thanks @prodigitalson. The risks of just typing something out quickly in the reply box.

Comment: @krillgar thanks for the help but when trying your code, its not working even if syntax error was corrected.

Comment: Like jfriend00 says in his answer, then we'll need extra guidance on what is going on: where the `#main-container` is, etc. I don't have my notes at home, but I do remember something about the incrementer not quite working correctly in something like that. Use the javascript console and keep an eye on what's going on and please provide more details if you can.

Comment: @krillgar the `#main-container` is an empty div that will serve as a placeholder for the images when called dynamically thats stored in the img folder. hope this helps. thank you