# Rails image slideshow

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I have an app which has one image on the homepage.  I would like that image to change to a different image in a slideshow format every 5 seconds or so.  Just between two images.

Is there a ruby gem for this or would this be something jquery could do?

Comment: Is your image stored in the database?

Comment: not right now, both are stored in the image folder

Comment: Then you should only need jquery...there are lots of other questions like this - try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8366684/jqueryreplacing-images-at-time-intervals. Just change the interval integer to 5000 if you want it to swap at 5 seconds. You can also add effects to fadeIn the images,etc. If that answer isn't working for you then let me know and I'll answer this question :)

Comment: And if you are using twitter-bootstrap, you could look into using their Carousel and just removing the links to Prev/Next img and replacing it with an interval. `$(function(){
     $('.carousel').carousel({
       interval: 5000
     });
  });` http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use gem then the best I can suggest is `'flex-slider-rails'`